# Why can't the end point work like what i want it to be?

Tags: c#, winforms

i am trying to do it according to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jc5eXYwTROg&list=PLAKPUAwWLX6STF4YdOGJzAk-C6thSs4Xu&index=15 but i cant seem to find the problem. It seems that the end coordinates arent changing the way it 
is supposed to. Can anyone help fix it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace 专题作业
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        startx = panel2.Width / 2;
        starty = panel2.Height / 2;
    }
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
    Graphics g = null;
    static int length = 0;
    static int lines = 0;
    static int increment = 0;
    static int angle = 0;

    static int centerx, centery, startx, starty, endx, endy;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        length = Int32.Parse(lengthbox.Text);
        increment = Int32.Parse(incrementbox.Text);
        angle = Int32.Parse(anglebox.Text);
        startx = panel2.Width / 2;
        starty = panel2.Height / 2;
        panel2.Refresh();
    }

    private void panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        pen.Width = 1;
        length = Int32.Parse(lengthbox.Text);
        g = panel2.CreateGraphics();
        for(int a = 0; a < Int32.Parse(linesbox.Text);a++)
            drawLine();            
    }

    private void drawLine()
    {
        angle += Int32.Parse(anglebox.Text);
        length += Int32.Parse(incrementbox.Text);

        endx = (int)(startx + Math.Cos(angle * .17453292519) * length);
        endy = (int)(starty + Math.Sin(angle * .17453292519) * length);
        Point[] p =
        {
            new Point(startx, starty),
            new Point(endx, endy)
        };
        startx = endx;
        starty = endy;
        g.DrawLines(pen, p);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain your problem more clearly. Now all there is it's "not working" and your guess at the reason but we have no idea what is going wrong.

Comment: it was supposed to draw a square if i type 90 degree in the angle and 4 lines, but instead, it only draw the number of lines correctly but the angle is messed up. When i type 90 degrees it draws to the right, and to the left when i type 180 degrees.

Comment: The first mistake you are making is `g = panel2.CreateGraphics()`. That creates a completely new graphics context, unconnected to the panel or screen, which is discarded after your method exits. You need to pass `e.Graphics` to `drawLines` and use that instead of `g`.

Comment: Would you mind showing it to me because im not that used to programming.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16871215) your question to clearly explain what the problem is. Do you not know how to draw to a panel? That is a basic beginner task you should be able to [easily find examples of](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx). Please put a tiny amount of effort to allow us to understand you.

Comment: im trying to draw according to the tutorial ive link above but the output is different.

Answer (score 0):

i changed the angle to math.pi * angle/180 instead of angle*0.17453292519 and it worked.